# Is there a faster way to get the index of the maximum value and keep count?

Tags: python, numpy, performance

Is there a faster way to get the count of each team having the highest score?

#### Input

```
# Random scores per player per round (each player corresponds to an integer from 0 - 100) 
scores_per_round = np.random.rand(10_000,100)

# 100,000 random teams of 8
teams = np.array([random.sample(list(range(100)), 8) for _ in range(100_000)])
```

#### Desired Output

```
# Count of top scores per team key being the index of the team in the teams array and the value being the amount of wins.
{
  0: 20,
  1: 12,
  ...
}
```

Currently I loop through the rounds, add up each teams score and then grab the maximum values index using `np.argmax` and store the count in a dictionary.

```py
import random
from collections import defaultdict

win_count = defaultdict(int)

# Random scores
scores_per_round = np.random.rand(10_000,100)

# 100,000 random teams of 8
teams = np.array([random.sample(list(range(100)), 8) for _ in range(100_000)])

# Loop through and keep track of teams wins
for round in range(10_000):
    win_count[np.argmax(np.sum(np.take(scores_per_round[round], teams), axis=1))] += 1
```

Comment: Would be ideal to add a **minimal** input/output example directly in the question, as text.

Comment: @mozway I tried adding a minimal input/output example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial code is slow because it allocates *pretty-big temporary arrays*. Iterating over them 10_000 is expensive because the RAM or the last-level cache are relatively slow (compared to the L1 cache or registers). Using **Numba** can fix this problem by computing the arrays *on-the-fly* in a more *cache-friendly* way.

Here is a simple *parallel* implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int32[::1](float64[:,::1], int32[:,::1])', parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def computeTeamWins(scores_per_round, teams):
    roundCount = scores_per_round.shape[0]
    result = np.empty(roundCount, dtype=np.int32)
    n, m = teams.shape
    assert m == 8 # See the comment below

    for r in nb.prange(roundCount):
        iMax, sMax = -1, -1.0
        for i in range(n):
            s = 0.0
            # Faster if the size is known as the loop can be unrolled
            for j in range(8):
                s += scores_per_round[r, teams[i, j]]
            if s > sMax:
                iMax, sMax = i, s
        result[r] = iMax

    return result

win_count = defaultdict(int)
for v in computeTeamWins(scores_per_round, teams):
    win_count[v] += 1
```

On my 6-core machine, it takes 0.8 second while the initial code takes 54.3 seconds. This means the Numba implementation is about *68 times faster*. If you cast `teams` to an `np.uint8` array, then the computation takes only 0.57 seconds resulting in a **95 times faster** execution (because of the caches). Note that this means the maximum integer value is bounded to 255 (included). Note that the final loop takes only few milliseconds.

Comment: I get `TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) array(float64, 2d, C), array(int64, 2d, C)` when including `'int32[::1](float64[:,::1], int32[:,::1])'` but if I remove it works fine, I am curious if this is needed?

Comment: This is because `teams` is of type `np.int64`. Keeping it in 64-bit is not efficient as it will take a lot of memory in cache and likely in RAM that will be slower to load. So to make it work, you need to cast it to `np.int32`. However, as said in the question, this is even better to cast it to `np.uint8` which takes 8 less time memory and should completely fit in the caches (possibly the L2 in new processors). In that case `int32[:,::1]` must be replaced by `uint8[:,::1]`. Creating it directly with the good type is even better if possible.